# Pruning a library with ProGuard

Tags: android, proguard, okhttp

I am running into the dex limit problem and I would like to avoid using multi-dex.
I noticed that `okHttp` has a separate internal package for `spdy` and since my app is not using it, I am trying to remove it.

I added this two lines to the `proguard.cfg`:

```
-printusage usage.txt
-assumenosideeffects class com.squareup.okhttp.internal.spdy.*
```

After building my app, I see in the `usage.txt` there are several `com.squareup.okhttp.internal.spdy` classes and methods, but when I run the `dexdump` script I still get:

```
    okhttp: 1461
        internal: 978
            http: 233
            huc: 160
            io: 18
            spdy: 373
            tls: 19
```

Can anyone answer what can be happening? Is there another way of removing a package from a library?

Comment: Post your `build.gradle` so we can see your dependencies. Proguard on release is what everyone should be using.

Comment: @JaredBurrows: What do you want to know from the `build.gradle`?

Comment: Post your `build.gradle` so we can see your dependencies.

Comment: Selectively omitting classes may cause OkHttp to crash on certain web requests.